# Wildfly-20.0.1-Final Timezone issue - Application resets to GMT from BST after few hours

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

Facing a peculiar issue with Wildfly-20.0.1.Final application server, we have wildfly running on a Windows server where the date time setting is in BST (British Summer Time) or UTC +00.00 (plus checked Automatically adjust clock to DST)

[date/time settings in windows server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTodk.png)

As there is no application configuration or code which converts the timestamp to any other timezone. We are calling new Date() which refers to the operating system's current date to fetch the date that is the same as set in date/time settings (above screenshot).

After 4-5 hours, the application changes/resets the time to GMT even though no configuration change/ date/time setting has been changed in the Windows server.

The system records the time in the application as GMT rather than BST and to resolve this issue we need to restart the application after deleting data and tmp files from the application server's standalone location.

Is anyone facing the same issue where time is getting reset in the wildfly application server?

Note: When a standalone program is written to fetch the timestamp from the Windows Server it points to BST rather than GMT. The issue is happening only in the wildfly application server.

Any hints will help! Thanks in advance!